# Make small pages fill browser height

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

How do you make small pages fill the browsers height so that the footer will be at the bottom not in the middle

for example

```
<body>
  <div data-offcanvas class="off-canvas-wrap">
  <div class="inner-wrap">
      <%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
    <section class="main-section">
       <%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
       <div class="row">
          <div class="large-12 columns">
            <%= yield %>
          </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <div class="footer-bottom">
       <div class="row">
       <div class="small-12 columns small-centered text-center">

          <ul class="footer-links">
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sitemap</a></li>
         </ul>
         <p class="copyright">© 2011–2014 Acme, Inc. All rights reserved.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a class="exit-off-canvas"></a>

  </div>
</div>

<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<script>$(document).foundation();</script>
  </body>
```

When there is a smaller yield the footer ends up in the middle of the page.  I'm okay with the footer being on the bottom, and I'm also okay with it being after a bunch of content, so scrolling is okay. I have searched and most poeple want a sticky footer which is not what i want.  I dont always want it on the bottom, i Just want each page to be a minimum of 1 page in height.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

**CSS**

```
html,
body,
.off-canvas-wrap,
.inner-wrap {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}

.inner-wrap {
    padding-bottom: [hight of your footer]px;
}

.footer-bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

Note: You're using `class=""` wrong. Unique elements should use `id=""`, if you're picky :-)

Comment: i usually use id when unique probably an oversight.  I'll try this out. thx

Comment: This appears to make it sticky and prevents page scrolling, also seems to overlap content

Comment: Just a fast dribbled down answer based on what you've provided. Could you please link to the actual page, post your current CSS or make a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

html, body should have height: 100%;

use min-height: calc(). You need to know the height of the footer.

http://jsfiddle.net/michaelburtonray/by10fkm9/

HTML

```
<div class="top">
  <div data-offcanvas class="off-canvas-wrap">
    <div class="inner-wrap">
      <%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
      <section class="main-section">
        <%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="large-12 columns">
            <%= yield %>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer-bottom">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 columns small-centered text-center">

      <ul class="footer-links">
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sitemap</a></li>
      </ul>

      <p class="copyright">© 2011–2014 Acme, Inc. All rights reserved.</p>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

.top {
    background: red;
    min-height: calc(100% - 156px);
}

.footer-bottom {
    background: green;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 156px;
}
```